# Is there a list of SharePoint 2007 WebParts, Features and ContentTypes that SharePoint installs with?

Tags: web-part, 2007, content-type, feature, installation

Where I can find a list of all the Web Parts, Features and Content Types that are available to a regular SharePoint installation?

What I need to do is identify any of the above in a SharePoint site that *are not* part of the standard Microsoft family that pack with SharePoint- as far as I can tell the most reliable way to do this is by comparison with a white list of all the ones that *are* available by default. Reflecting the object model gives a list of the ones that are installed on any given site, but I'm reluctant to try and install/use every possible member of each of those categories on one site if I can avoid it.

It seems quite likely to me that this data is around somewhere, but it's quite hard to search for because I'm looking for a list and SharePoint is largely built around lists so I've been unable to find search terms that don't return thousands of irrelevant results.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a list of the web parts MOSS has out of the box...

- [MOSS out of the box webparts](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/bobbyhabib/archive/2007/09/17/moss-out-of-the-box-web-parts.aspx)
- [Out of the box list of webparts sharepoint 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/ketaanhs/archive/2008/02/12/out-of-the-box-list-of-web-parts-sharepoint-2007-or-moss-or-wss-3-0.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! "Out Of The Box" being the critical search term here. Clearly I wasn't thinking outside the box...

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 6):

I've found the following list of feature names by running Dir /B on the SharePoint `TEMPLATES\FEATURES` directory, which appears to be a cheeky yet effective solution:

> AddDashboard, AdminLinks, Analytics, AnalyticsLinks,
>   AnnouncementsList, BaseSite, BaseSiteStapling, BaseWeb,
>   BaseWebApplication, BasicWebParts, BDCAdminUILinks, BDR,
>   BizAppsCTypes, BizAppsFields, BizAppsListTemplates,
>   BizAppsSiteTemplates, BulkWorkflow, BulkWorkflowTimerJob,
>   ContactsList, ContentLightup, ContentTypeSettings, ctypes, CustomList,
>   DataConnectionLibrary, DataConnectionLibraryStapling,
>   DataSourceLibrary, DeploymentLinks, DiscussionsList, DMContentTy,
>   eSettings, DocumentLibrary, EawfSite, EawfWeb, EnhancedHtmlEditing,
>   EventsList, ExcelServer, ExcelServerSite, ExcelServerWebApplication,
>   ExpirationWorkflow, featurenames.txt, FeaturePushdown,
>   FeaturePushdownTask, fields, GanttTasksList, GlobalWebParts,
>   GradualUpgrade, GridList, Hold, ipfsAdminLinks, IPFSAdminWeb,
>   IPFSSiteFeatures, IPFSWebFeatures, IssuesList, IssueTrackingWorkflow,
>   LegacyDocumentLibrary, LinksList, ListTargeting,
>   LocalSiteDirectoryControl, LocalSiteDirectoryMetaData,
>   LocalSiteDirectorySettingsLink, MasterSiteDirectoryControl,
>   MigrationLinks, MobilityRedirect, MySite, MySiteBlog, MySiteCleanup,
>   MySiteHost, MySiteLayouts, MySiteNavigation, MySiteQuickLaunch,
>   Navigation, NavigationProperties, NoCodeWorkflowLibrary, OffWFCommon,
>   OSearchBasicFeature, OSearchCenralAdminLinks, OSearchEnhancedFeature,
>   OSearchPortalAdminLinks, OSearchSRPAdminLinks, OsrvLinks, OsrvTasks,
>   OssNavigation, OSSSearchSearchCenterUrlFeature,
>   OSSSearchSearchCenterUrlSiteFeature, PageConverters, PictureLibrary,
>   PortalLayouts, PremiumSite, PremiumSiteStapling, PremiumWeb,
>   PremiumWebApplication, ProfileSynch, Publishing,
>   PublishingB2TRHop2SiteFilesUpgrade, PublishingB2TRSiteFilesUpgrade,
>   PublishingLayouts, PublishingPrerequisites, PublishingResources,
>   PublishingSite, PublishingStapling, PublishingWeb, RecordsManagement,
>   RedirectPageContentTypeBinding, RelatedLinksScopeSettingsLink,
>   ReportCenterCreation, ReportCenterSampleData, Reporting,
>   ReportListTemplate, ReviewWorkflows, SearchAndProcess, SearchWebParts,
>   SharedServices, SignaturesWorkflow, SiteSettings, SitesList,
>   SkuUpgradeLinks, SlideLibrary, SlideLibraryActivation, SpellChecking,
>   SPSDisco, SPSearchFeature, SpsSsoLinks, SRPProfileAdmin,
>   StapledWorkflows, SurveysList, TasksList, TeamCollab,
>   TranslationWorkflow, TransMgmtFunc, TransMgmtLib, UpgradeOnlyFile,
>   UserMigrator, ViewFormPagesLockDown, WebPageLibrary,
>   WebPartAdderGroups, WikiWelcome, WorkflowHistoryList,
>   WorkflowProcessList, XmlFormLibrary,

I'm not certain that is all of them, or that all of those are the feature names I will find in the SharePoint library, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

this is a better source of information;

- [SharePoint Products Comparision](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/d/c/1dc632e8-71e1-466f-8a2f-c940f1438e0a/SharePointProductsComparison.xls)

Comment: What you have done there is totally not understand the question. In Sharepoint there is a type of object that can be added to a site, which in their infinite wisdom Microsoft chose to call a "Feature" - I was looking for a list of these.